# What do i insert after "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?"

Tags: php, database, authentication

So i have a full code from an online tutorial and unfortunately when they provide the code there are certain areas which i have no idea what to put in. I know this could be very basic, but to people who don't know much about sql and php codes, they too will have some difficulty figuring out the basics.

Alot of people put the hard questions but never the simple basic questions that starters like me struggle to understand.

*Here is the [a link](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php)! where i got the information from.*

I've tried going on **google** and going through **stackoverflow**, and **webdevtrick** but all the questions or concerns the people have are harder solving problems than the basic one i have.

## Validate credentials

```
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
```

So i've tried to put a *1*, *0*, and i've tried putting *'username'* in the **question mark area** but no luck. All it backfires me with is *Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.*

**CODE AFTER THE VALIDATE CREDENTIALS**

```
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            

                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

I bet it's so basic, but i'm hoping that if someone else who is also having difficulty with this will help them and understand what they should put in that statement. Thank you for the help, and if you need more information please let me know.

THANK YOU!

**EDIT FOR THE PERSON WHO WANTED TO SEE THE WHOLE CODE**

````
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
  header("location: welcome.php");
  exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            

                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>```
````

Comment: Include where you initialize your $stmt variable. Also move your `$param_username = $username;` before `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);`

Comment: What do you mean initialize my $stmt variable?

Comment: include in your code where you set $stmt to something. what do you have before `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);`

Comment: @altoids I just included it above the whole code in case you wanted to see it

Comment: You're not initializing `$link` anywhere. It has to be something like `$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");` Add it right before `if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#example-1914 look at procedural style

Comment: i believe its inserted in the Config File where the link is located in **/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */**
`$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);`

Comment: The problem here is not that “the tutorial didn't say anything about it” as you complain, but that you skipped ahead. https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-prepared-statements.php has a very detailed explanation of what prepared statements are and how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't put anything **in place of** the question mark; the question mark is **meant** to be there. The next line, `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` *replaces* the question mark with `$param_username` programatically.

You will, however, need to assign something to `$param_username` **before** attempting to use it in this statement:

```
$param_username = 'name';
$sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

The above will ultimately query `SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = name`.

In your (updated) example above, you set `$param_username` as `$username`, and `$username` as `trim($_POST["username"])`. If there is not a `name` field of `username` on an `<input>` in a `<form>` in the referring page, this value will be empty. Make sure to check for the presence of both `$username` and `$password` with:

```
if(
    isset($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["username"]) &&
    isset($_POST["password"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])
) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you! I was so confused, i didn't know if i needed to fill it in myself since the tutorial didn't say anything about it.